# Rcmdr problems: Dataset is not shown

Tags: r, if-statement

I uploaded a dataset using `Rcmdr` and got the normal message:

> exp <- read.table("D:/experiment/data per r- AMENDED - no NA.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

So far so good. But, when I click on “View DataSet”, the dataset is not shown and I get the following messages:

- On the Rcmdr window:

  > library(relimp, pos=14)
- On the main R:

  > Error in if (packageAvailable("relimp") && ncols <= getRcmdr("showData.threshold")) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Now, some discussions seem to suggest that it is, because there might be some NAs, but I’ve got no missing data.

The weird thing is that if I use the command to show my data set, it is shown.

**Questions:**

- Is there something wrong with my dataset?
- How do I solve this problem?
- What does `&& ncols <= getRcmdr("showData.threshold")) mean?`

Comment: Is this a problem of R or a problem of Rcmdr? Have you tried other GUIs?

Comment: I am so new, that I actually have to ask you. What do you mean with "have you tried other GUIs"? SORRY

Comment: E.g. RStudio is another GUI. Depending from the operating system of your computer there are also other GUIs.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface